In R how to log a model from a file into mlflow
I received a model as a file my_model.rds, and I would like to load it into mlflow.
File was created as
saveRDS(my_model, "my_model.rds")

If I try the following
my_model <- readRDS("my_model.rds")
mlflow_log_model(my_model, "my_model")

I get error 404: 'RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST; No experiment for node found.
My understanding is that the model saved in rds preserve no information regarding the experiments, and this information is required by mlflow to register the model. Is there a way to add this information either when the rds file is created or ex post with some empty experiment?
Does anyone have any advice on how load the model?

Without knowing how a model was created and saved and without knowing what packages you have been using, this is too vague to answer.

@IRTFM It was saved using saveRDS, I have no access to the code used to create it, I attached what is indicated as requirements.

@IRTFM from the error message it seems the problem is that the rds file is not associated to any experiment, do you know how to associate some experiment object (even empty) to the model?
